# domain name cloaking with nginx

Tags: nginx

How can I do the following in nginx?

I have a website hosted on example.com/id/44, I want to have my domainname test.com linked to that url. I also want that the domain name in the url sticks to test.com instead of the example.com url.

So test.com --> example.com/id/44

I currently have the following in nginx but the url doesn't sticks to test.com

```
server {
server_name www.test.eu test.eu;
access_log /srv/www/www.test.eu/logs/access.log;
error_log /srv/www/www.test.eu/logs/error.log;
root /srv/www/www.test.eu/public_html/src/public;

location / {
    rewrite ^/ http://www.example.com/id/5 break;
}
```

}

Is this possible in nginx?

Comment: 2 domains point to same server? If so, what does directory structure look like?

Comment: Just like most hosters do (cloaked domains), They don't need to be on the same server. But in my case they are.

Comment: What is document root of `example.com`?

Comment: well there is a way to give a redirect code such as 301 or 301 but that literally says "visit that url instead". You can use location and alias and such to say /thing maps to this folder but thats about all i know you may do

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No.

Nginx cannot do rewrites across hostnames, it can only rewrite the URI. You can either do it another way or you'll have to use something other than Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to think about using nginx as a reverse proxy for test.com.
Something like this might be interesting for you:

```
server test.com {
               location /  {
                       proxy_pass http://www.example.com/id/5;
               }
}
```